# How to wake up a user mode sleep process in kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I want to wake up a user-mode process in kernel . The process is blocked by calling sleep() in user mode . I called function wake_up_process() in kernel , but the process did not wake up after the wake_up_process() call.  I do not know why .
Does anyone know how to wake up a user-mode sleep process in kernel ?  Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

If the process called `sleep()`, it will wake up either when its time comes, or when it gets a signal. `wake_up_process` will just cause the kernel to test if the time has come, and go to sleep again.

So send a signal.

Comment: So what kind of signal can work, I tried sending a SIGALARM , but it killed the process.

Comment: Do you know what exactly does the signal handling do so that the process will not go to sleep again ?